# OpenGL make texture scale up and not clamp

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I have a texture in a game that clamps to the edge instead of linearly scaling up. These are the parameters I'm providing OpenGL with:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EGDE);
```

How should I change them in order to make the texture scale up?

These are the vertices I'm giving OpenGL:

```
typedef struct{
  float positionX;
  float positionY;
  float textureX ;
  float textureY ;
} textureVertex;

textureVertex vertices[4] = {
      {-3.5f,  3.5f, -1.0f,  1.0f},
      {-3.5f, -3.5f, -1.0f, -1.0f},
      { 3.5f, -3.5f,  1.0f, -1.0f},
      { 3.5f,  3.5f,  1.0f,  1.0f}
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify texture coordinates for your vertices. CLAMP just tells OpenGL what to do when the coordinates go outside the range 0 -> 1. It does not say where that range *is*.

Comment: I have, I don't understand what's wrong. I've just added the coordinates. Could you have a look?

Comment: No, your texture coords lie in the range [-1, 1].  They should be in [0, 1].

Comment: I'm going to have to ask for a small and compilable example of the problem there are too many things you might have missed for me to guess at.